# How to run triggerRebuild URL

Tags: database

Apparently I am not allowed to ask for clarification in the post, so can someone please elaborate on this?

Sounds good. To be sure, please execute ///civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1 which fixes the trigger and function definitions in the database."

It looks like I need to do this, but where/how? I asked my hosting provider and they referred me back here.  :/

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the too terse explanation you received on the other answer, using a shortform that experts are used to. If you are running a Drupal site, example.com, then to rebuild your triggers navigate in your browser (by pasting in the url) to http://example.com/civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1 , for WordPress it is http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fmenu%2Frebuild%3Freset%3D1&triggerRebuild=1 , and for Joomla it is https://example.com/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1.

Without a reference to your earlier question, I'm not sure which version of CiviCRM you are running. FWIW, I think this fixup may have changed in recent versions.

Make sure you have admin CiviCRM permissions.

Comment: Thanks, Joe.  Actually, it was answer to someone else's question, but it wouldn't let me ask there for clarification.  I did try to paste the URL replacing example.com with my domain but it says I do not have permission to execute this URL.  :/  It had to do with the MyISAM database engine issue.  I changed them all to InnoDB, but still getting the error in the System Report. Should I contact my hosting provider and ask them to run the URL or is there a permission I can change myself?

Comment: Hi, Joe.  I'm using CiviCRM 4.7.6 on Drupal 7.43.  I pasted the URL (replacing with my domain name) and received a successful message, however, the system is still showing the MyISAM error.  Any thoughts about how to fix it?